# ASP.NET Model View Presenter project structure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, mvp

I am just starting a new ASP.NET project and using the MVP pattern. I did consider the MS MVC but it is not released yet and would be a big learning curve for some people on the team, so I opted for MVP now and possibly future projects MVC.

Anyway, it seems I will have a single Controller/Presenter class for every webform I have it the project. This is a lot of extra classes, essentially doubling the number of files in the web project. Is this how other people structure MVP or what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common misconception -> "More files/classes == more complex"

The reason we chose to follow a UI separation pattern is to help separate concerns, make code easier and cheaper to change and maintain and (big, important **and**) we can unit test the complex parts and still keep the UI layer slim.

I'm going with the beta ASP MVC. The reason being, that while it is still only a beta (PDC very soon, that may have an impact on release and we've had 5 preview releases) it has a better framework to support this style than I could write in a reasonable time frame.

You could of course go with another framework, like castle monorail.

Comment: I would personally love to go with ASP.NET MVC. I have used it myself for www.jobtree.com.au. Unfortunately many developers don't like the idea of loosing their GridViews and other visual components. :-P

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of it depends but in most cases that is really the way it ends up going.

I personally use a n-tier architecture with data, business, presentation code.  (Who knows what actual format I follow).  I do get a lot more files than if I did everything in the aspx, but the code is much easier to manage.

Comment: This sounds pretty much like what I have. I have a Model, Services and Web layers.

Answer (score 0):

To your question - I have seen many different takes on MVP and seen nothing that reduces the number of files, and I can't think of a way to reduce the number of files.

In my experience, I have reused view interfaces and even code behinds where the view structure is identical, but presenting different data. And you could also think of reusing the controllers where applicable.

I think it is worthwhile to note that having more files will be a natural consequence of moving to a more agile and test-drive development and developers will find it more and more natural as they go. (Just like some of us find it very natural having lots of methods inside a single file...)